# Did Oppenheimer quote the Bhagavad Gita after the Trinity test?

Tags: quotes, nuclear-weapons

There is an often repeated story that Robert Oppenheimer, one of the leaders of the Manhattan Project, quoted the Bhagavad Gita after witnessing the first nuclear test.

One version of the story is told [here](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3215156):

> Robert Oppenheimer, the scientist who directed the Manhattan Project that built the two atomic bombs dropped on Hiroshima and Nagasaki in August 1945, remained morally ambivalent about his role in the entire matter. He summed up the effect the first experimental test, code named Trinity, of an atom bomb had on him; he said, “Now I am become Death, the destroyer of worlds”, a rough translation of a verse from the Hindu scripture, the Bhagavad Gita.

I recently saw [this tweet](https://twitter.com/JamesConran1/status/1480348047708098560?s=20) claiming he did not (the tweet is a photo but the source is from the letters pages of the [London Review of Books](https://www.lrb.co.uk/the-paper/v40/n08/letters)) in 2018 and, in full, says:

> Thomas Jones repeats the story that Robert Oppenheimer quoted the Bhagavad Gita after witnessing the first successful nuclear weapons test in New Mexico: ‘I am become Death, destroyer of worlds.’ I once had the chance to ask his brother, Frank, who was standing next to him at the time, what Oppie’s actual words were. Frank’s recollection was that he said: ‘I guess it worked.’

> Jeremy Bernstein
> New York

So did he say the quote after the test?

Comment: Even if his brother's recollection of his first words are correct, that doesn't mean he didn't also use the quote in his reaction to the test.  I believe the original source for the quote was Robert Oppenheimer himself, so it may be hard to contradict.

Comment: @antlersoft There is also the possibility that his later thoughts were projected back to the immediate aftermath of the test and people confused what the claimed to have though with what he actually said.

Comment: Relevant: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fa5kA9w7t0Q

Comment: A similar post on other SE site - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22979/which-verses-from-gita-were-referred-by-j-robert-oppenheimer-the-father-of-atom

Answer (score 95):

**No.**

In the 1965 documentary "[The Decision to Drop the Bomb](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T2W9CxVVMAc&t=1555s)", Oppenheimer described the moments after the bomb's explosion:

> We knew the world would not be the same. A few people laughed, a few people cried. Most people were silent. I **remembered** the line from the Hindu scripture, the *Bhagavad Gita*; Vishnu is trying to persuade the Prince that he should do his duty and, to impress him, takes on his multi-armed form and says, 'Now I am become Death, the destroyer of worlds.' I suppose we all **thought** that, one way or another.

In the book *[Brighter Than a Thousand Suns: A Personal History of the Atomic Scientists](https://archive.org/details/BrighterThanAThousandSuns-PersonalHistoryOfAtomicScientists/page/n165/mode/2up)*, written based on first-hand interviews with the Manhattan Project scientists and others, it is noted that Oppenheimer initially recalled (but again, did not say) a different quote from the *Bhagavad Gita*, before recalling the famous "destroyer of worlds" quote:

> If the radiance of a thousand suns were to burst at once into the sky, that would be like the splendor of the mighty one...

Both sources agree that Oppenheimer *remembered* the quote, but didn't actually say it out loud.

Comment: Totally plausible and easy to see how some later reported he *said* it rather than just *thinking* it.

Comment: OT: Doesn't that part of Bhagavad Gita actually say "I am become Time, the destroyer of worlds"?

Comment: @JohnEye The translation is disputed, but that isn't the point of the question.

Comment: Seems more like "technically no, but in spirit, yes". After all, he said it (in the documentary) and claims he said it then since he was thinking it originally. There's no reason to think he spent 20 years trying to think up a cool quote to retrofit.

Comment: How loudly did he remember it?

Comment: @JohnEye: Oppenheimer was reading the Bhagavad Gita in the original Sanskrit; his translation of that passage differs somewhat from the standard English translation (which did not yet exist at the time).